# Formatting ListView Content During onCreate() method (getting ListView children)

Tags: android, listview, formatting, view, listactivity

I am using a ListActivity which fills from a database.

Depending on a the information stored in the record I want to format the row in the listView.  For example, I have a boolean coulmn which specifies whether the current entry has been 'marked off' and if so then I want to set the strike-through formatting flag on one of the textViews inside the list row.

The way I thought that I could do this was by getting the ListView from the ListActivity and then getting the view that I wanted to change by using the getChildAt() method and then inflating and formatting the view as required.  However at this point there are no children in the object and I cannot find another way to acquire the individual views.

I'm trying the following code now but the two text views that I'm trying to inflate come back as null.  The code is within an inner class of 'ShoppingList' which is the ListActivity so it's probably something wrong with the way that I'm calling the getView() method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
             {
                 View thisView = adapter.getView(i, ShoppingList.this.getListView().getRootView(), ShoppingList.this.getListView());
                // inflate views
                TextView view_item_name = (TextView) thisView.findViewById(R.id.view_item_name);
                TextView view_item_checked = (TextView) thisView.findViewById(R.id.view_item_checked);
             }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the Adapter is for. :) The `getView` method of your adapter (or if you're working with a `CursorAdapter`, `newView` and `bindView`) is where you should format the view for an item based on the data being presented before it is shown in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply adamp. I thought that may have been the case but was scared off by the arguments that need to be passed into the getView method - could you advise? I'll try to edit the code I'm trying now into the original question

Comment: Romain and I did a talk on ListView at Google I/O last year, video and slides here: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Comment: You might also want to take a look at some of the list examples in the ApiDemos sample project in the SDK.