# getting listview children onCreate() 

Tags: android, listactivity

I put this code in the end of onCreate() method of ListActivity

```
ListView list=getListView();
for (int i=0;i<list.getAdapter().getCount();i++) {
    TextView tv= (TextView) list.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);  //i simplify this string for example
}
```

it doesn't work because ListView has no childs yet - it's size 0; however .getAdapter().getCount() returns not 0.

What should i use instead of list.getChildAt(i) to make this code correct?

---

UPDATE: i think, this is what i need [Formatting ListView Content During onCreate() method (getting ListView children)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358270/formatting-listview-content-during-oncreate-method-getting-listview-children)
but i don't get the solution of that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is added to the adapter so instead of `list.getChildAt(i)` use `lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null)` to get the view

Comment: so i changed my code to this:
`for (int i=0;i<getListView().getAdapter().getCount();i++) {
 TextView tv= (TextView) list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}` 
it compiles but doesn't do anything

Comment: Better create your custom adapeter and inside getView() method.